# Where has BigInt gone?

Tags: c#, biginteger

I have started on the Project Euler problems. Currently I am on Problem 13 which requires you to provide the first ten digits of the sum of 100, 50 digit numbers.

I decided I would try to solve it with a big int class in C#. I looked around on the internet and there are tons of example code with them. However, I can't seem to find BigInt in my Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 11):

In the .NET Framework 4.0 it's found in System.Numerics.dll.  Add a reference to that assembly to gain access to System.Numerics.BigInteger.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful reply

Comment: For previous versions of .NET (namely 3.5), provided the F# runtimes are available, `Microsoft.FSharp.Math.BigInt` might be an alternative option.